# Custom order in TSQL: page of N records with max X of a value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to order a table such that every 'page' with N number of records (i.e page size) includes a maximum of X records of each field value.

Example table values:

```
Value
-----
a
a
c
a
b
b
a
c
b
a
c
c
c
d (and so on..)
```

(Value can be any text, in random order. For simplicity, I've used alphabets.)

If page size is 5 and max of each field value is 2, the results can be as listed below (or in a different random order), as long as every 5 consecutive records have a max of 2 records of each character:

```
Value
-----
a   ┐
a   |
c   |── first page of size 5 with max 2 records of a value
b   |
b   ┘
a   ┐
a   |
c   |── second page of size 5 with max 2 records of a value
b   |
c   ┘
a   ┐
c   |── last page of size 5 (or less) with max 2 records of a value
c   |
d   ┘
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are talking about actual data pages where SQL stores the data, or do you have a field (or some other determination of) "page"? ref http://www.practicalsqldba.com/2012/08/sql-server-understanding-data-page.html

Comment: In my case, page is just a virtual separator. It's just N number of rows.

Comment: It sounds like if the third value was 'a' that you'd only return the first 2 items on the first 'page', correct?  Your example doesn't show what happens when there are more than 2 records with a given value.  Is this for some kind of UI pagination?

Comment: @James That's correct. Each page (set) of N rows (5 in example) should include a maximum of X rows (2 in example) with same values, and rest should be placed in another page. It's not really UI based, but more for batch processing purposes.

Comment: Do you need a 'page number' to come back from a SQL query or stored procedure? It sounds like you just want to stream the data and keep track of the page number as you go on the client side.  You may be able to write T-SQL to generate a page number, but I'm pretty sure that SQL isn't the best way to do this.

Comment: @James Don't need the 'page number'. Just the sort order should follow the 'maximum X records of a value per N records' rule.

Comment: @Nick, I'm really not understanding you.  What sort order are you talking about?  OP says "random order".

Comment: @James Yeah, sort order is not the correct way to put it. Random, but with one rule: 'maximum X records of a value per N records'.